# Unable to show QR image in SSR nuxtjs for package vue-qr

Tags: vue.js, qr-code, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I'm using  https://github.com/Binaryify/vue-qr in Nuxtjs type SSR project. I'm having an issue to render the qr.
The QR code is not a picture. Vue-qr is still stored as a label in the html structure. The QR code becomes the background of the label.

My local is working fine
[image]

But this is in SSR hosting.[image]

Thank you.